# Deserializing a json string to an object array and then cast it to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

This is the json string

```
[{"ProductIdentifier":"{test:'some data'}","validationCompleted":0}]
```

I am trying to deserialize an object into an object array which works fine but when i am trying to cast it back to an dictionary i am getting an exception can anyone please help me with this  thank you.

```
    m_receiptsList is an object[] 
 m_receiptsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(pastJsonString,
                                                        new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});
  for(int i=0; i<m_receiptsList.Length; i++)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> receiptItem = (Dictionary<string, object>)m_receiptsList[i]; 
 bool breceipt = receiptItem["validationCompleted"].Equals(0);
}
```

// exception while doing this saying cannot cast object m_receiptList[i] to dictionary.

Comment: What's the runtime type of `m_receiptList[i]` then?

Comment: The general idea is that you write yourself a class which has properties which correspond to the format of the JSON data. Then you add serialization-specific attributes to the class and the properties and use that one to deserialize the JSON message. ``JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyNiftyClass>(...)``.

Comment: Where's the Dictionary going to get the string for the Key? You can't cast an array to a Dictionary, they're entirely different things. You might be able to turn it into a `List<object>`, but not a Dictionary.

Comment: @user2225104 Hi yes i could write that but server data might change time to time so if i have the system.object then i don't have to manage the class whenever there is an update from server.

Comment: @bali182 it is a system.object and it has an idictionary of string and jtoken.

Comment: Where does `i` come from in your snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Json.NET to deserialize your JSON as an array of dictionaries, you need to tell it to do so:

```
        object[] m_receiptsList;
        m_receiptsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(pastJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

Incidentally, setting [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) isn't going to help you because your JSON sample has no type information.  If it did, there would be a property `"$type"` at the beginning of your object(s).

Also, JSON.Net will convert a JSON integer into a `long` unless told otherwise, so you would need to do:

```
        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> dict in m_receiptsList)
        {
            bool breceipt = dict["validationCompleted"].Equals((long)0);
        }
```

Comment: Yes i did exactly that thank you so much for the answer anyway :)